# SQL calculated column with case statement and table join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

Okay, I've done some web digging and cannot seem to find how to make this situation work or even if it is possible.

I am using SQL Server 2008 and have a calculated column where i am trying to figure some values regarding foreign currency exchange rates.

Although one single table might be easier in the long run, I would like to use the correct solution which involves two different tables.

table `t1` houses a log of transactions. table `t2` houses basic information for a given currency. The two tables can be joined using the `currencyCode` attribute.

The sticky part comes with currency dependent calculations. Presently the calculations only differ for `CR1` `CR2` `CR3` or `CR4` but in the future as more currencies are added, the potential exists for the new currencies to differ. So ideally, a new row would be added to `t2` and a bit flag (`flagCurrencyCalc`) set that specifies the alternate calculation be used or not used.

So the present formula looks something like this:

```
(case when [currencyCode]='CR1' OR [currencyCode]='CR2' OR [currencyCode]='CR3' OR [currencyCode]='CR4' then (formula1) else (formula2) end)
```

As you can see, i would have to manually go in and alter the formual by adding another OR statement with the new currencyCode.

Would it be possible to do something along the line of:

`(case when t2.flagCurrencyCalc=True` for a given currency code in a record found in t1 `then (formula1) else (formula2) end)`

???

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access another table in a computed column directly (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)).

Here are some options.

You can simplify your formula using `in`:

```
(case when currencyCode in ('CR1', 'CR2', 'CR3', 'CR4')
      then (formula1)
      else (formula2)
 end)
```

You can use a view:

```
create view vw_tablename as
    select t.*,
           (case when currencyCode in (select currencyCode from ListOfCurrencies where . . . )
                 then (formula1)
                 else (formula2)
            end)
    from t;
```

You can define a function to check the currency.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. If the other table you are proposing is say

```
CurrencyFlag (curr_code varchar(5), flag bit)

curr_code    flag
---------    -----
C1            1
C2            0
...
```

then your case can have a sub query

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2,
CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT flag FROM CurrencyFlag t2 WHERE t2.curr_code = t1.currencyCode) = 1 
    THEN formula1
    ELSE formula2
END , t1.col3
FROM 
table1 t1
```